# Update database using SqlCeDataAdaptor

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I populate a listview from a Dataset that accesses sqlserver in visual studio 2008 express edition. I've been trying to update the listview and database simultaneously.

SettingTxt.Text references a textbox

With the following code, I've been able to update the list view with the information entered into the textbox, but the same update is not performed in the database. If anyone can help me resolve this, I would greatly appreciate it. I know there are alot of forums online regarding this exact problem, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
thisConnection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=AugMedDB.sdf;Password=");
thisConnection.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Patient SET Setting = \'" + SettingTxt.Text + "\' WHERE (PtID=0) AND (EquipID=1) AND (Control='Lever')" ;

SqlCeDataAdapter adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
adp.UpdateCommand = cmd;
dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][2] = SettingTxt.Text;
adp.Update(dataSet);
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Moved from an answer:

What I currently have is:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE id=0";
SqlCeDataAdapter adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = dataS.getDataSet();
adp.Fill(ds, "Patient");

SqlCeCommand comm = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Setting = 'value' WHERE (PtID=0)";
adp.UpdateCommand = comm;
adp.Update(ds, "Patient");
```

### And I'm not understanding all the tutorials I find. Thanks in advance.

Update:

Yet even something as simple as the following doesn't update the database:

```
SqlCeConnection thisConn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=AugMedDB.sdf;Password=");
String query = "UPDATE Patient SET Setting = 'TopyTruck' WHERE (PtID=0) AND (EquipID=1) AND (Control='Lever')";
thisConn.Open();
SqlCeCommand commd = new SqlCeCommand(query, thisConn);
commd.ExecuteNonQuery();
thisConn.Close();
```

Comment: Re that last part: check the return of ExecNonQuery. And maybe use try/catch to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your UPDATE statement is not suitable for an Adapter.Update(), for that it needs parameters and must be aligned with the SELECT statement.

You could try to execute that Command directly (w/o the adapter) or create a better update statement (using the dataset designer ).

---

Update

After filling the dataset,

- generate the other SQL statements with a CommandBuilder (I think it exists for SqlCe)
- or use your use your own Update command **without** the adapter. Just call `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Tip 1: It may help to create a temporary (WinForms) project and use the VS tools to "Add a Datasource". You can look in the Dataset designer how VS generates the commands etc.

Tip 2: There are other options available, like entity framework. Datasets are (becoming) an "end of life" tech.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little more? I am new to this. What I currently have is :

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your help. I actually found the source of the problem. I had multiple references to the database; one within my project and another copy in bin/debug. I was correctly updating the copy in bin/debug but I was looking at the copy in my project. Once I deleted all copies, other than the one in bin/debug, it all worked and made sense. Now I see the updates in the database in bin/debug/